# Element not interactable (NG-click) Selenium Python .click() in a DIV

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hello everyone forgive I think I can not really explain my problem, I will try again, if they can not understand me very well is that sometimes my English written fails a lot sorry

What I want to try is to automate the access to a web that I leave and link here
[RUNT](https://www.runt.com.co/consultaCiudadana/#/consultaVehiculo)

The first part I have solved that is to enter the data to the form and resolve the im not to robot in send

I'm going to post all the code in python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import pandas as pd
import threading
import time
import csv
import os


# options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument(
#    r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\RADEON\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\user Data\default')
#
# options.add_extension(r"C:\Users\RADEON\Documents\Web Driver\Selenium\exs.crx")

# driver = webdriver.Chrome(
#    executable_path="C:\\Users\\RADEON\\Documents\\Web Driver\\chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe",
#    chrome_options=options
# )
#
# driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#
# driver.get("https://www.runt.com.co/consultaCiudadana/#/consultaVehiculo")
# assert "Consulta Ciudadano - RUNT" in driver.title
#
# wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
# wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "noPlaca")))
#
#
# wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "noPlaca")))


class Runt:

    def __init__(self, placa, nit, time):
        self.placa = placa
        self.nit = nit
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.options.add_extension(
            r"C:\Users\RADEON\Documents\Web Driver\cp.crx")

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            chrome_options=self.options)

        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, time)
        self.wait_API = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 150)

    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def run(self):

        driver = self.driver
        wait = self.wait
        wait_api = self.wait_API
        driver.get("https://www.runt.com.co/consultaCiudadana/#/consultaVehiculo")

        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "noPlaca")))
        placa = driver.find_element_by_id('noPlaca')
        placa.clear()
        placa.send_keys(self.placa)

        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "noDocumento")))
        owner = driver.find_element_by_name('noDocumento')
        owner.clear()
        owner.send_keys(self.nit)

        # /html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[1]

        wait_api.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
            By.XPATH, "//*[@id='captcha']/div/div[2]/a[1]")))

        while (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='captcha']/div/div[2]/a[1]").get_attribute("innerText") != "Solved"):
            print("Search Solution....")
        print("solution found...")

        if(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='captcha']/div/div[2]/a[1]").get_attribute("innerText") == "Solved"):
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[8]/button").click()

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.panel.panel-default>div.panel-heading>h4.panel-title a"))).click()

        vigente = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[@id='pnlRevisionTecnicoMecanicaNacional']/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]")

        print(vigente.get_attribute("innerText"))


runt2 = Runt("aqd470", 63364079, 2)
# runt1 = Runt("aqd470", 45884847, 2)
#
# thread1 = threading.Thread(target=runt1.run)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=runt2.run)
#
# thread1.start()
thread2.start()
# r'C:\Users\RADEON\Documents\Web Driver\csv.csv'
```

Ignore the threads was doing some tests.

When running this program on the aforementioned web waiting to solve the I am not a robot and send the form, and the code appears that I want to get the information

but the information does not appear in the html until clicking on the following div

```
<div class="panel-heading" ng-click="togglePanel('pnlRevisionTecnicoMecanicaNacional');
                        consultarDetalle('RevisionTecnicoMecanicaNacional')">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <i class="i_hoja s_25_o1 ib"></i>
                            <a> Certificado de revisión técnico mécanica y de gases (RTM)</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
```

U can use this example data to enter "AFD329" For Nplaca,"6656954" For Documento

The other fields can be left as default 
I need to click on that element to load the rest of the query would appreciate a lot if you can help me the TRACEBACK IS

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RADEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\RADEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "bypass.py", line 86, in run
    "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[1]").click()
  File "C:\Users\RADEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\RADEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\RADEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\RADEON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: 1. The error trace you have posted is error on `"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[1]").click()`, but this is not part of the code you have shared. Please check and update the latest code/trace in the question.
2. I could not find any element with this xpath `//*[@id='captcha']/div/div[2]/a[1]`, what element are you trying to click on?